# Browserify: how to debug in different browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browserify

I am considering [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to develop a web app in modules.

Since browserify is based on a build step to generate a bundle JS script, how can I debug original files separately and not the generated app in different browsers (also IE8 and IE9)?

NOTE:
the actual debug mode in browserify enables source maps to original files, but it is only working  in Chrome.

Comment: As far as I understand, browserify does't change the files themselves, just appends them to one another (and maybe does some small editing to resolve naming conflicts). your code should still be the same.

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to debug files separately instead of checking just one bundle js file. At the moment I have been able to do that in Chrome, enabling the debug mode in browserify that do the source map, but not in other browsers

Comment: Source maps are the only way to accomplish what you want to do; and as you've discovered, not all browsers support them. You could always use RequireJS and its syntax which would allow you to avoid the build step required by Browserify (and therefore provide every browser with truly separate JS files for debugging).

Comment: Thanks for answers. I am considering also other solutions as you proposed.